# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS still not offering dist-upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Tags: lts, do-release-upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. From what I understand, by now, `sudo do-release-upgrade` should offer an upgrade to 18.04 LTS, but I still get `No new release found.` when trying that. What else could I try?

(I realise that I probably need to supply more information to identify the issue, so please let me know which info I should be adding here.)

Comment: Is your system up to date with all available updates from the 16.04 archive?

Comment: As far as I can tell (i. e. doing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` shows no further available updates), yes.

Comment: Instead of `sudo apt-get upgrade`, try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Also open `Software Sources` and check what you have under `Release upgrade > Show new distribution releases`.

Comment: @DKBose `upgrade` will list anything that `dist-upgrade` would otherwise pull in (this is usually kernel updates or such which pull in new dependencies that are not installed yet). Also, the setting for update notifier should have no bearing on the function of the `do-release`upgrade` script.

Comment: (Indeed, ``dist-upgrade`` did not do anything materially different from ``upgrade``.)

Answer (score -1):

MOST IMPORTANT: Disable all power saving, screen time-out, screen 
saver, auto logout, etc settings.

[1] In Software & Updates set `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version''
    to`For any new version''.

[2] From the command line run ``update-manager''

That should do it.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't, though … :\